# _IMAGE_DOS_HEADER symbol not found

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I have recently installed windbg inside windows 7 in Vmware .. Installed windows SDK and Windows Symbols.

But still when I open executable "notepad.exe" inside windbg, and run the following
dt _IMAGE_DOS_HEADER  command, it says symbol not found.

I have PATH set already _NT_SYMBOL_PATH=SMVSRV*c:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

Tried the same on windows XP ... same issues ..

Please advice.

Thanks !

Comment: [Using the Symbol Server technology](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503/en-us)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set it to **srv****http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols. Despite what documentation is saying, prefix **symsrv** does not work for me, while **srv** does:

```
0:000> .sympath srv**http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: srv**http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Expanded Symbol search path is: srv**http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
0:000> .reload
Reloading current modules
...................
0:000> dt _IMAGE_DOS_HEADER
ntdll!_IMAGE_DOS_HEADER
   +0x000 e_magic          : Uint2B
   +0x002 e_cblp           : Uint2B
   +0x004 e_cp             : Uint2B
   +0x006 e_crlc           : Uint2B
   +0x008 e_cparhdr        : Uint2B
   +0x00a e_minalloc       : Uint2B
   +0x00c e_maxalloc       : Uint2B
   +0x00e e_ss             : Uint2B
   +0x010 e_sp             : Uint2B
   +0x012 e_csum           : Uint2B
   +0x014 e_ip             : Uint2B
   +0x016 e_cs             : Uint2B
   +0x018 e_lfarlc         : Uint2B
   +0x01a e_ovno           : Uint2B
   +0x01c e_res            : [4] Uint2B
   +0x024 e_oemid          : Uint2B
   +0x026 e_oeminfo        : Uint2B
   +0x028 e_res2           : [10] Uint2B
   +0x03c e_lfanew         : Int4B
0:000>
```